# Disappearing footer nav when clicking on menu button - media query

Tags: css, media-queries, footer, nav

I have a disappearing footer nav problem! At @979 media query - a navigation button appears on the top of the screen with a drop down menu. However, when I click on this button the same info that appears in the footer nav totally disappears...
Any thoughts please?

Here is the CSS:

```
header nav {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

header nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1d5671;
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

header nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

header nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(29,86,112,0.92);
    width: 100%;
}

header nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #00a8ef;
}

header nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

header nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

header nav ul li a {
    padding: 1em 2%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #00a8e5;
}
```

/*nav end----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*footer nav----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

```
footer nav  {
    display: inline;
}

footer nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

footer nav ul li a {
    background-color: #00a8e5;
    width: 100%;
}

footer nav ul li {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    clear: left;
}
```

/*end footer nav----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

Comment: Where is the code for the button. Is it JavaScript that is making that work? I'd take a guess that the button is targeting 'nav' so effecting both the head and footer nav elements.

Comment: Brilliant @BillyMoat ! Thanks ever so much.

Comment: Another question then. Is that once the menu button appears and is clicked, the menu drops down, which is what I want. However, when I hover on a menu item that has a sub-menu, the sub-menu appears at the bottom of the menu, rather than under the item and also disappears when I am not hovering on that particular menu item... Any ideas?